# Can not send same action from different components

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I have two components which should send action to controller, but only one of them does work

My controller:

```
`import Ember from "ember"`

CourseIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    openStep: (unit, step, routeName)->
        @transitionToRoute(routeName, unit, {queryParams: {scope: step}})
`export default CourseIndexController`
```

And my components:

```
UnitTableStateComponent = Ember.Component.extend  
  step: ''
  unit: ''

  openStep:( ->
    @sendAction('action', @get('unit.id'), @get('step'), 'unit')

  ).on('click') //it works
`export default UnitTableStateComponent;`


ExamTableStateComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  exam: ''
  step: ''
  openStep:( ->
    @sendAction('action', @get('exam.id'), @get('step'), 'exam')

  ).on('click') //id does not works
`export default ExamTableStateComponent;`
```

I can not understand what's wrong with ExamTabeStateComponent or with whole my code

ember version: 1.13.8

Comment: Have u made binding on both components actionName="actionName"

Comment: Can you also show your templates so we can see how you're using the components?

Comment: You should probably also call the action something other than `action`, since that's the name for the default action for when you click a component.

Comment: Why are you doing `.on('click')` instead of a regular `click` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your component pass the action like kristjan mentioned

```
{{UnitTableStateComponent oneStep="oneStep"}}
```

Then in the component controller you can do this

```
oneStep: function(){
    this.sendAction("oneStep");
}
```

You can do this for both components and should have better luck - let me know.

Side note, component names should include a "-" if I'm not mistaken